# code for clock generation in structural verilog

Tags: verilog, iverilog

I was trying to teach myself verilog programming from "The Verilog HDL" book by Thomas Moorby. In one of the exercises, they asked to generate a clock using structural verilog only (except for the $monitor part of course).

I tried the following:

```
module clock();
    wor clk;
    assign clk=0;

    initial begin 
        $monitor($time,,"clk=%b", clk);
        #100 $finish;
    end

    assign #5 clk = ~clk;
endmodule
```

Problem is, it works in iVerilog 0.9.7, but for version 10.0 and above, it does not work.. I simply get undefined value for clk!

Does not seem like a bug in iVerilog, otherwise it would probably have been fixed in one of the 10.x releases. Is there any other way to get this working? Also, what is wrong with the current code (if any) ?

Answer (score 2):

this is a messy code you have. usually clock generation done with regs as one of the following

```
reg clk;
initial begin
    clk = 0;
    forever 
         #5 clk = ~clk;
end
```

or

```
 always 
     #5 clk = ~clk;
 initial 
     clk = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Strange code, you are resolving `clk` drives using an or-gate behaviour. First `assign` is constantly driving `0`. Second `assign` is inverting the resolved value. But what is the initial value of the second `wor` input? Wouldn't that second `assign` produce `X` in the first place (`X` ored with `0` would give you `X`)? Have your tried running it in the simulator or at least drawing somewhere what hardware do you want to get? It's like you're feeding and inverter with `0 or'ed with X` which will produce `X`.

If you want to model a clock you can:

1) convert first `assign` into `initial begin clk = 0; end`

2) second `assign` to `always`

3) make `clk` `reg` type

If you want a synthesizable clock generator you would require a source of oscillations, PLL, etc.

Comment: I don't think the code I was using is synthesizable. But I was not using wire, but wired or (wor) as the clk. So, it is supposed to be able to driven by multiple sources which would be or-ed. So, although constantly driven my a 0, after 5 time units, it should toggle to 1 since I am assigning ~clk. And then every 5 time units, it should toggle, shouldn't it? And this is exactly the behavior I was seeing in iverilog 0.9.7 (simulation result), but 10.x versions are behaving as you mentioned.

Comment: Also, in the second point, did you mean "make clk reg type"? In that case, the solution is obvious, but I was specifically trying to avoid any initial or always blocks (as mentioned in the problem I was trying to solve).

Comment: My understanding is that you get a wired-or at the input of the inverter, the inverter is uninitialized and thus produce floating values. Or-ing X and 0 will still feed X to the inverter and produce X.